# Count the elements in the list only once without duplication in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My input should be a integer. Based upon the integer value, I have to give strings in the list..and my code is:

```
words = []
i = int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,i):
   j= str(raw_input())
   words.append(j)

unique_word_count = len(set(words))

print unique_word_count
for j in words:
    print words.count(j),
```

and my **input is**

```
4
bcdef
abcdefg
bcde
bcdef
```

and the output is

```
3
2 1 1 2
```

but I need output like this:

```
3
2 1 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Do you need to retain an association between a word and its count?  That's not in your output.

Comment: i dont want any association between them

Answer (score 2):

You're sooooooo close!

```
for j in set(words):
    print words.count(j),
```

Take note that, since you're reporting each word's count only once, you've lost a strong association between each count and the word it represents.  Both `set` and `Counter` will lose that ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
print collections.Counter(words)
```

For your input you'd get:

```
Counter({'bcdef': 2, 'bcde': 1, 'abcdefg': 1})
```

Comment: i need output only like this 3 in first line and 2 1 1 in second line

Comment: @Bhavani Note that `len(Counter(words))` is `3`.

Comment: @Bhavani is the 2nd line ordered by when the element is first seen in `words` or based on frequency? If it's frequency then you can call `.most_common()` otherwise you could create a custom OrderedCounter

Comment: @Bhavani Put another way would the 2nd line output for input `['a', 'b', 'b']` be `1 2` or `2 1`?

Comment: that was repeated element so it gives 2 but i dont need it's duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to convert the list to a set in your second loop:

```
for j in set(words):
    print words.count(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `from collections import Counter`
and

```
words = []
i = int(input())
for index in range(0,i):
   j= input()
   words.append(j)

unique_word_count = Counter(words)
print(unique_word_count)
```

its output the amount of each word